# Replace + on form input with -

Tags: html, forms, validation

How can I, via JS, replace + with - on a string passed trhu an input?

Also how can I make "window.open" open in the same table?

Thanks!

```
<div id="formBusca" style="display: none; position: absolute; z-index: 999; right: 30px;">
<form class="form-inline"  onsubmit="buildurl()">
<input id="campoPes" style="box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19); margin-top: -8px" type="text" class="form-control" name="campoPes" placeholder="Faça sua busca...">
<button style="box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19); margin-left: 5px; margin-top: 0px" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Buscar</button>
</form>          </div>
        </div>        
      </div>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function buildurl() {
        var searchText = document.getElementById("campoPes");
        window.open("https://gazetadocerrado.com.br/?s=" + searchText.value);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Javascript you can use the replace function with a regex to change the `+` chars to `-` chars, like this:

```
searchText.value.replace(/[+]/g, "-")
```

For your other question: if you want to open another page in place of the current browser page, use `window.location = "http://...";`